# Can one tell from the outside whether a papaya has seeds?

Tags: fruit, seeds, papaya

Some papayas have no or virtually no seeds:

[image]

Sometimes it has many seeds

[image]

Can one tell from the outside whether a papaya has seeds?

Answer (score -1):

If the fruit was known to come from a parthenocarpic (meaning seedless) plant, then yes.

For example, the distinctive “mountain papaya” fruit from a babaco shrub (Carica pentagona ‘Heilborn’), which related to Papaya, is parthenocarpic. It originates from the Andes, but is now cultivated, for local and international markets, in California and New Zealand.

Comment: And how does one tell from the outside whether a papaya is seedless? (Assuming there isn't a sign next to it saying "seedless papayas" or "Carica pentagona Heilborn").

Comment: If the fruit was known to come from a parthenocarpic (meaning seedless) plant, then yes = If the fruit was NOT known to come from a parthenocarpic (meaning seedless) plant, then NO. Once it has been identified then skin blemishes would still make it identifiable. ;)

Comment: In that case, does this really answer the OP's question? I assume they're not asking about papayas which are clearly marked as seedless.

Comment: The papaya itself doesnt need to be marked as seedless, just that it would need to be known to come from a tree that produces seedless fruit. Like navel oranges, once you know a navel orange is seedless you do not need them to have labels to know they are seedless.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. If they knew whether or not it came from a seedless plant they would not need a means of identifying it.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible to see an orange is seedless when you know it is a navel orange?